# Remap or group values from a dictionary using Snowpark or python UDF within Snowpark

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for a way to remap/group values in a new column using Snowpark and can't seem to find anything in the documentation.
Usually I would use something like a .replace() function but I don't believe this exists in Snowpark.

The result should be similar to this:

Original DataFrame

| Item |
| --- |
| Apple |
| Banana |
| Potato |
| Onion |

New DataFrame

| Item | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Fruit |
| Banana | Fruit |
| Potato | Vegetable |
| Onion | Vegetable |

Comment: Where would the mapping be stored? What's your current code?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa the way that I would normally do it with python would be from a dictionary but I can't find a function in Snowpark that would do the equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the answer to this question you can use a replace function in Snowpark to achieve this. Example code:

```
dict = {'Apple':'Fruit','Banana':'Fruit', 'Potato':'Vegetable', 'Onion':'Vegetable'}

df.withColumn("Category", col("Items")).replace(to_replace=disc, subset=["Category"]).show()
```